# Using PublicClientApplicationBuilder and AcquireTokenSilent for chaining Web API calls

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm working on an AD proof of concept using a console application and `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` to call Web API A and to call Web API B which also calls Web API A. (API A is just the "Weather" example, and API B just wraps API A.)

My call in API B to `HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(ApiAyeScopes.AccessAsUser)` keeps throwing:

> IDW10203: The 'scope' or 'scp' claim does not contain scopes 'api://A0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/access_as_user' or was not found.`

How can I resolve this and get the call from API B to API A to work?

I have the direct call to Web API A working. Here's how I authenticate:

```cs
static Boolean Authenticate()
{
    // See the answer to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4b2aff3-eeb1-4204-82ed-ca80232c2523/error-aadsts50076-due-to-a-configuration-change-made-by-your-administrator-or-because-you-moved-to?forum=WindowsAzureAD.
    __identityApplication =
        __identityApplication
        ?? PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444")
            .WithAuthority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/me.org/v2.0")
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:11596")
            .Build();

    string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://A0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/access_as_user" };

    __authenticationResult =
        __identityApplication
            .AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
            .WithExtraScopesToConsent(new String[] { "api://B0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/access_as_user" })
            .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false)
            .ExecuteAsync()
            .Result;

    Console.WriteLine("Logged in as {0}.", __authenticationResult.Account.Username);

    return null != __authenticationResult;
}
```

Here's how I call Web API A from the console, which works:

```cs
static List<WeatherForecast> GetWeatherForecast()
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, __authenticationResult.AccessToken);

    var response = httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:1001/weatherforecast").Result;

    var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeatherForecast>>(jsonString);
}
```

Here's how I call Web API B, which partially works:

```cs
static List<WeatherForecast> GetAugmentedWeatherForecast()
{
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://B0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/access_as_user" };
    var apiBeeAuthenticationResult =
        __identityApplication
            .AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, __authenticationResult.Account)
            .ExecuteAsync()
            .Result;

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, apiBeeAuthenticationResult.AccessToken);

    var response = httpClient.GetAsync("https://localhost:1101/weatherforecast").Result;

    var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WeatherForecast>>(jsonString);
}
```

In Web API B, I have the following:

```cs
public class ApiAyeScopes
{
    public const String WeatherRead = "api://A0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/ReadWeather";
    public const String AccessAsUser = "api://A0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444/access_as_user";
}

[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { ApiAyeScopes.AccessAsUser })]
[Authorize(Policy = ApiBeeAuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToReadAugmentedWeatherRequired)]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<AugmentedWeatherForecast>> Get()
{
    var apiAyeScopes = new String[] { ApiAyeScopes.AccessAsUser };

    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore#code-in-the-controller
    HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(apiAyeScopes);

    var originalResult = await _apiAyeClient.GetWeatherForecasts();

    return originalResult.Select(wf => new AugmentedWeatherForecast(wf));
}
```

The code to get the access token is:

```cs
String accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new String[] { ApiAyeScopes.WeatherRead });
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are looking to resolve your code from API B to API A to work and API B and API A. On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO) serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API.

Learn more here:

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/on-behalf-of

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

The OBO flow is represented by the steps that follow, which are illustrated in the diagram below.
[image]

More guidance can be found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof